# How to make sure the explicit operator throws the exception when converting null? (not nullable)

Tags: c#

I have an explicit operator on the class `MyVO`, which should be non-nullable.

```
public class MyVO : ValueObject<MyVO>
{
    public string Value { get; } // Should never be null

    private MyVO(string v) => Value = v;

    public static explicit operator MyVO(string vo)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vo)) throw new Exception('...');
        return new MyVO(vo);
    }
```

However, `(MyVO)null` will not raise an exception. The body of the method will not be run.

```
var myVO = (MyVO)null; // myVO will have the null value
```

How to make sure it's not null?

Comment: Create a static `FromString` method and document that that is the right way to go. Don't provide an `explicit` operator at all.

Answer (score 9):

> How to make sure it's not null?

By "it" I assume you mean "the result of the cast from `null` to `MyVO`".  If that is not what you mean, please clarify the question.

You cannot.

An important rule of C# is **a user-defined conversion never "wins" when it conflicts with a built-in conversion**.  It is legal to convert `null` to any class type, and so a cast of `MyVO` on the expression `null` will *always* result in a null reference. The compiler does not even consider the user-defined conversions if a built-in conversion works. (Believe me; I wrote that code!)

As D Stanley's answer correctly points out, if the `null` is the *value* of any expression of type `string` then the user-defined conversion is called; there is no built-in conversion from `string` to `MyVO` so the compiler looks for an applicable user-defined conversion and finds one.

Since it hurts when you do what you're doing, you should probably stop doing what you are doing. An explicit conversion is probably not the right way to implement the desired behaviour.

> I guess my question should be how to make `MyVO` not nullable.

Upgrade to C# 8.  C# 8 supports non-nullable annotations on reference types.

Note that the non-nullable annotation should be properly thought of as an *annotation*. The type system does not *guarantee* that the value of a variable annotated with a non-nullable annotation will *never* be observed to be null. Rather, it does its best to warn you when the code looks like it is wrong.

---

While we are looking at your code, I notice that you are using `ValueObject<T>`, which I assume you have obtained from something like

https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/value-object-better-implementation/

Let me take this opportunity to caution you that there are pitfalls to using this pattern; the constraint that you *think* or *want* to be applied to `T` is not the constraint that *is* applied to `T`.  We often see things like this:

```
abstract class V<T> where T : V<T>
{
  public void M(T t) { ... }  // M must take an instance of its own type
}
```

If we have `class Banana : V<Banana>` then `Banana.M` takes as its argument a `Banana`, which is what we want.  But now suppose we have `class Giraffe : V<Banana>`.  In this scenario, `Giraffe.M` does not take a giraffe; it takes a banana, even though `Giraffe` has no relationship with `Banana` at all.

The constraint does *not* mean that `M` always takes an instance of its own class. If you are trying to construct a generic type with this kind of constraint in C#, you cannot; the C# type system is not rich enough to express that constraint.

Answer (score 3):

`null` can be implicitly converted to any reference type, so the compiler is not using your explicit cast operator. try

```
string s = null;
o = (MyVO)s;
```

or just inline it

```
o = (MyVO)((string)s);
```

Comment: Should be `(MyMvo)((string)s)` perhaps.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: Hmm, I guess my question should be how to make `MyVO` not nullable.

Comment: @ca9163d9 Make it a `struct`? I don't see how that relates to your question.

Comment: No, it's a class which inherits `ValueObject`.

Comment: also `MyVO((string)null)`

Comment: @ca9163d9 Prior to C#8 there was no mechanism to prevent one from setting a reference type variable to `null`. C# 8 introduces nullable (and by extension non-nullable) [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references).

Comment: I note that the logic in your first statement -- null is not a string, so the compiler does not use the user-defined operator -- is not quite right. C# does allow a built-in conversion to be placed "on top" of a user-defined explicit conversion. For example, suppose we had a user-defined explicit conversion from int to Turtle, and then the code `(Turtle)2.0`.  C# would not reason "a double is not an int, therefore the user-defined conversion does not apply".  C# would reason "the user intends the double to be first converted to int".

Comment: Similarly, the compiler could reason here "there is a built-in conversion from null to string, so the user intends the chain of conversions to go from null to string, and from string to `MyVO`."  The compiler never gets a chance to make that deduction because a rule of the language is "if a built-in conversion exists, do not look for user-defined conversions".  A built-in conversion already exists from null to MyVO *directly*, so no user-defined conversion is looked for.  C# defaults to the simplest available conversion here.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks for the clarification. Always appreciate your expert insights.

Comment: You are very welcome. The user-defined explicit conversion code is some of the most complicated code in the semantic analyzer. It is chock full of subtleties and this is then exacerbated by the fact that Roslyn is required to be backwards compatible with bugs that go back to the C# 2.0 days. (Adding generics and nullables led to a number of bugs being introduced in user-defined explicit conversions and these bugs have been preserved because real code depends on them.)

Comment: @EricLippert Side note - I met you at a Microsoft MVP conference about 15 years ago. You and I sat at dinner together with a larger group and talked about everything from the Seattle weather to language design and compiler theory. I thoroughly enjoyed the conversation and have enjoyed your insights ever since.

Comment: @DStanley: Thanks for those kind words! Indeed, I do miss the MVP dinners. They were a lot of fun.